# Update from SQL Server 2012 Express to SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

(Newbie alert - I have used SQL Server mostly only as an extension of Visual Studio).

I'm trying to get Management Studio 2014 (SSMS) and Visual Studio 2013 to use SQL Server 2014 Express instead of SQL Server 2012 Express.

They both appear to be installed:

[image]

When I start  SSMS and do the login selecting `MyPC\SQLExpress`, the resulting server =

```
  MyPC\SQLExpress (SQL Server 11.0.5343 - MyPC\Me)
```

`11.0.5343` is 2012, as best as I can tell.

How can I get SSMS and VS to point to SQL Server 2014 Express instead of 2012?

UPDATE:  in response to the suggestions below, here is what Configuration Manager shows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to show the SQL Server services you have either in Configuration Manager or the Services Control Panel applet. You have two instances of SQL Server Express, but only one of them can be named `SQLExpress` explicitly, so you must have given the 2014 instance a different name when you installed it. You would have to connect to it using `MyPC\WhateverThatNameIs` or, possibly, `MyPC` if you installed a default instance (which is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your SQL Server Configuration Manager and see which instances are installed - it should show you the two SQL Server Express instances, and their instance names:

[image]

The instance name appears after the `SQL Server` text in the brackets; `MSSQLSERVER` signifies the **default, unnamed** instance, while SQL Server Express by default gets installed as `SQLEXPRESS`. In your case, that appears to be the 2012 instance - the 2014 instance must have a different instance name (or possibly it's installed as the unnamed, default instance - in that case, just use `.` or `(local)` as the server/instance name to connect to it).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, please update above showing configuration manager (apparently for 2014);  only one instance of SQL Server is showing (SQLExpress).